# Split tagit input data into multiple rows

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, tag-it

I am using jquery.webspirited.coms tagit jquery, which is working correctly in the sense of creating the tags, separating on the front end, but when I POST the data, it's only posting the last tag as the value to the database..

I can't find any documentation on how to correctly install the addon apart from what code to put in the header etc, here is the header code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

  $('#topic').tagit();    

  $('#topicGetTags').click(function () {
    showTags($('#topic').tagit('tags'))
  });
  $('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    tag = $('#topic').tagit('tags');
    console.log(tag);
    for (var i in tag)
      $('form').append("<input type='hidden' name='tags[]' value='"+tag[i].value+"' >");

  });
  function showTags(tags) {
    console.log(tags);
    var string = "Tags (label : value)\r\n";
    string += "--------\r\n";
    for (var i in tags)
      string += tags[i].label + " : " + tags[i].value + "\r\n";
    alert(string);
  }
});
</script>
```

The input

```
<ul id="topic" name="tags[]"></ul>
```

The tagit.js file itself has almost 500 lines, so rather than copy/paste it here, here is a link to it.

http://webspirited.com/tagit/js/tagit.js

Also here is the INSERTION code, incase it's something I need to look at there

```
$tags = isset($_POST['tags']) ? $_POST['tags'] : null;

if (is_array($tags)) {
foreach ($tags as $t) {
    // escape the $t before inserting in DB
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tags (tags) VALUES('$t')";
}
```

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 0):

Change the hidden input name to `name="tag[]"` and you'll receive an array in `$_POST['tag']` in your PHP script - at present you're overwriting the previous input which is why you're only receiving one item.

You can then loop over the array and insert them as required in your database.

Comment: I put the [] back in like so  $('form').append("<input type='hidden' name='tag[]' value='"+tag[i].value+"' >");  but now it's inserting blank data..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$tag = isset($_POST['tag']) ? $_POST['tag'] : null;

if (is_array($tag)) {
    foreach ($tag as $t) {
        // escape the $t before inserting in DB
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tags (tag) VALUES('$t')";
    }
} else {
    echo 'Invalid tag';
}
```

*Updated: Change below code (Use `tage[]` for name and wrap append code in `{}`. May be you have something between `for` and `append` and your `append` code executing after `for` loop end)

```
for (var i in tag)
    $('form').append("<input type='hidden' name='tag' value='"+tag[i].value+"' >");
```

As below:

```
for (var i in tag) {
    $('form').append("<input type='hidden' name='tag[]' value='"+tag[i].value+"' >");
}
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() :(

Comment: Make sure you are assigning the `$_POST['tag']` to `$tag` before `foreach`, Answer udpated

Comment: It's now only inserting the last tag, better than empty though, I have updated the original post to reflect my current code with you suggestions.

Comment: That means there is only one tag in `tag = $('#topic').tagit('tags');`. Please add output of `console.log(tag);` in question. Which you have in `$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){` handler

Comment: sorry can you please tell me again but reworded, not sure exactly what you are suggesting.

Comment: What is the output of 'console.log(tag);' in `submit click handler`

Comment: I put an "echo "'. $sql .'" before $result and got 
INSERT INTO tags (tags) VALUES('three')

The tags I entered were "one" two" "three".

Comment: May be `append` code is executing only once. Answer Updated: `*Updated: Change below code`